# jsPlumb: zoom in and zoom out issue when dragging the endpoint

Tags: php, css, html, jsplumb

I am tring to load a jsPlumb flowchart, but I am having a problem when I use zoom in and zoom out. addpoints are not displaying correctly.

[image]

I have used setZoom function for zooming.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to repaint the jsPlumb objects when zoom operation is performed:

```
jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
```

I think you need to include above code in the setZoom() function.

Example for window resize:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
            jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
});
```